# does there exist a continuous function that follow these sentences?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

does there exist a function f that follows this sentence?:
the domain of f is real number set, and f is continuous in every real number
if x is a rational number, f(x) is an irrational number
and if x is an irrational number, f(x) is a rational number

Comment: i meant continous in every real number

Comment: wow this is exactly the answer! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such continuous function.Assume that $f$ is not constant.Note that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable so $f(\mathbb{Q})$ is countable.And $f(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})\subset \mathbb{Q}$ so $f(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})$ is also countable.This means $f(\mathbb{R})$ is countable.But as $f$ is continuous so $f(\mathbb{R})$ must contain some intervals like $[a,b]$ and this will contradict the countability of $f(\mathbb{R})$.So $f$ must be constant but this will not hold beacause of the condition.